# How do I upload binary content from an HTTP post into a MYSQL database through PHP without using PHP's file handling functions?

Tags: php, mysql, http, file, post

This may not be possible, but I'd like to ask anyway and see if there's a creative solution out there.

I'd like to have a "file" form field on my site that uploads a file into a BLOB field in a MYSQL database.  I must use PHP to accomplish this task.

Normally, I know you would open the temp file found in the $_FILES array, using fopen(), then add the data to the db that way.  In this case however, the fopen() function, and pretty much all other file handling functions (file_get_contents, etc) are disabled in php.ini.

Is there a way to get the file data from the HTTP post and put it into the MYSQL database without relying on the file handling functions built into PHP?

P.S. shell_exec is also disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without fopen or file_get_contents you cant upload any file to your database .. why you don't try ftp functions (fput ,etc) ??

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` variable, , then you should be able to parse out the file data manually.

Comment: Care to add example code to demonstrate how one might do this?

Comment: From the manual: $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data".

Is there a way to get a file's contents to show up in $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA?

Comment: I did not see that comment in the documentation.